# Azure data factory - how to force in order processing of slices

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a daily data slice in data factory. I'd like to suspend processing if the previous slice has not arrived. I'd like all subsequent data to queue behind until the missing slice arrives.

Is this possible in data factory?

Answer (score 0):

You can define policy properties such as concurrency.

```
"policy": {
                "timeout": "01:00:00",
                "concurrency": 1,
                "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst"
            }
```

Concurrency: 1 means only one slice can run at a time. So if the previous slice has not gone to ready state your next slice will not run.

Timeout can be used to fail a slice that is hanging for too long.

And then execution priority order enables you to customize that logic.

Answer (score 0):

Note that setting concurrency will only work if there are multiple slices available at the same time. Each slice is distinct and autonomous from each other, so if the slice from 2 days ago fails or is missing but the slice from yesterday turns up and validates then it will be processed.
You could create an output in your pipeline in an activity that is dependant on your daily activity and make that an input dependency for your daily activity, so if the slice for 2 days ago is not processed the dependant output is not created so the subsequent run won't start.
It's a bit of a juggling act but you should be able to use SliceEnd in the output name and SliceStart in the dependant input to give the same name and maintain a day to day dependency

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about my previous answer, I don't think that will do what you want. Rather it will ripple a failure through remain slice processes because the dependant input file is not where it should be.
Creating inter-slice dependencies is very difficult in data factory.
One technique I have used before is to stage the incoming data with slicentifier and slicestart and then use a stored procedure to process the relevant slice. If you logged which ones had been done you could prevent processing until the previous one was complete. This would still mark the activity as complete though so not really suspending processing

Comment: Sounds like what I've got in mind isn't yet supported. Your posts certainly give some insight into strategies though!